# UI Component [JavaFX Group] loses its position while the window is resized ... occurs only after scrolling horizontally

Tags: javafx-2

Please go through the image below.
[image]

In the above image you can find that horizontal scrolling is not started.
Now visit the After Scroll image of the same contents...

[image]

Now in the second image you can see that horizontal scrolling is done ...
JFXPanel contents are scroll horizontally... Which was perfect...
Now the third image will describe the problem....

[image]

It is liitle bit stretched to see as it is maximized...
You can see that the JFXPanel contents have changed their original position...
Moreover the contents must start with X_DisplaceMent = 0.0 [X-Cordinate], which was done automatically in the first two images...
All the contents are nodes like [Rectangle,Line etc.. ], after that all are placed in Group node...
And this Group node is set in the ScrollPane  through

```
js.setContent(Group node);
```

Each component is placed with given x,y cordiante value .. then how did this happen while doing the maximized ?
Please help me to find the root cause ...

Thanks in advance...

Here are some facts that cause the problem.

```
- Start Position of Scene : 0.0 
- Start Position of Group in Scene : 49.5 
- Width of the root : 364.5 


- Start Position of Scene : 0.0 
- Start Position of Group in Scene : 63.5 
- Width of the root : 364.5 

- Start Position of Scene : 0.0 
- Start Position of Group in Scene : 83.5 
- Width of the root : 364.5
```

Whenever we drag the window horizontally Group is moving in the scene... That should not happen... how to avoid this ...

Ok... Here is the MCVE.....

There is a Frame. which contain SplitPane having vertical split.
The SplitPane will show the contents of two JFxPanels.
Both fxpanels are having rectangle on same x cordinate but Y cordinate is different.
And both the fxPanels are horizontal scroll sync. Not bi-directional. When you scroll lower panel horizonatally, the upper panel will get scrolled due to horizontal sync.

Here is the code for fxPanel 1...

```
public class FxPanel1 extends JFXPanel
{
private ScrollPane scroll ;


public ScrollPane getJs() {
    return scroll;
}
public void setJs(ScrollPane js) {
    this.scroll = js;
}

private boolean initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
    Scene scene = createScene();       
    fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    return true;
    //craneAssignmentChartView.setFxPanel(fxPanel);        
}
private Scene createScene() {
    Group root = new Group();

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10.0, 20.0, 800, 40);
    rect.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.TRANSPARENT); 
    rect.setStroke(javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED);

    AnchorPane anchor = new AnchorPane();
    anchor.getChildren().add(rect);

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setHgap(0);
    grid.setVgap(0);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));        
    grid.add(anchor, 1, 0); 

    root.getChildren().add(grid);

    ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();
    scroll.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
    scroll.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
    scroll.setContent(root);
    setJs(scroll);
    return new  Scene(scroll, javafx.scene.paint.Color.WHITE);      
}

private void createUI(final JFXPanel fxPanel)
{
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            initFX(fxPanel);                
        }
    });
}
public FxPanel1( JFXPanel fxPanel)
{
    createUI(fxPanel);
}
}
```

Now the code for second fxPanel looks like ...

```
public class FxPanel2 extends JFXPanel
{
private ScrollPane scroll ;

public ScrollPane getJs() {
    return scroll;
}
public void setJs(ScrollPane js) {
    this.scroll = js;
}
private boolean initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
    Scene scene = createScene();       
    fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    return true;
    //craneAssignmentChartView.setFxPanel(fxPanel);        
}
private Scene createScene() {
    Group root = new Group();

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10.0, 180.0, 800, 40);
    rect.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.TRANSPARENT); 
    rect.setStroke(javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED);

    AnchorPane anchor = new AnchorPane();
    anchor.getChildren().add(rect);

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setHgap(0);
    grid.setVgap(0);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));        
    grid.add(anchor, 1, 0); 

    root.getChildren().add(grid);

    ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();
    scroll.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
    scroll.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
    scroll.setContent(root);
    setJs(scroll);
    return new  Scene(scroll, javafx.scene.paint.Color.WHITE);      
}

private void createUI(final JFXPanel fxPanel)
{
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            initFX(fxPanel);                
        }
    });
}
public FxPanel2( JFXPanel fxPanel)
{
    createUI(fxPanel);
}
}
```

The main class looks like ....

```
public class DemoToCheckUIAlignment extends JFrame
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final DemoToCheckUIAlignment demo = new DemoToCheckUIAlignment();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            JFXPanel panel1 = new JFXPanel();
            FxPanel1 fxObj1 = new FxPanel1(panel1);

            JFXPanel panel2 = new JFXPanel();
            FxPanel2 fxObj2 = new FxPanel2(panel2);

            DemoToCheckUIAlignment frame = new DemoToCheckUIAlignment();
            frame.setSize(800, 500);               
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  

            JSplitPane chartSplitPane = new JSplitPane();
            chartSplitPane.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
            chartSplitPane.setDividerLocation(200);
            chartSplitPane.setDividerSize(2);
            chartSplitPane.setTopComponent(panel1);
            chartSplitPane.setBottomComponent(panel2);

            demo.provideScrollSyncBetweenFXPanels(fxObj1.getJs(), fxObj2.getJs());


            frame.getContentPane().add(chartSplitPane);
            //frame.getContentPane().add(panel2);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}


public static void provideScrollSyncBetweenFXPanels(final ScrollPane upperSP, final ScrollPane lowerSP)
{           

            lowerSP.hvalueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() 
            {               
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
                        Number old_val, Number new_val) 
                {
                    upperSP.hvalueProperty().set(new_val.doubleValue());
                }
            });
}
}
```

Now to check the problem follow the simple steps...
Ofcorse run the program...
Scroll the bottom Panel ....that is FxPanel2...
And maximized the window .... The x - position for the inner contents is changed now...
which does not happen with Swing....

Here are the screen shots where the problem reproduce for the attached MCVE....Please go through the images....

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try using a subclass of [`Pane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) instead of using [`Group`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html)? For example, a [`Hbox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html).

Comment: How can it will be effective ? I mean does the Group has such overhead.... Anyways I have tried with HBox and the result is still same ..

Comment: `Group` is not directly resizable. So it does not gets resized by the scene while the window is resized from the corner.

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it? I am pretty sure the problem is with using Group, but things will be clear if you can post one.

Comment: @ ItachiUchiha : Please check the MCVE....

Comment: I tried and cannot reproduce the behavior. [Supported Image](http://i.imgur.com/Kt6seDz.png?1)

Comment: ahh.... I am not able to see the "Supported Image" ... Blocked by administrator... It's like  problem will reproduce only when you scroll the bottom panel first and then maximized.... this way you can check the x-position of the rectangle for both the scenarios..... before maximized and after maximized...

Comment: let me attach the screen shots...

Comment: Please see the screen shots .. you may get the idea about the issue I am facing...

Comment: Can't reproduce on `Mac OS + Java 1.8.0_25`. I will retry this on windows and ubuntu and get back to you.

Comment: the setFitToWidth method sets true for the scroll pane, the content shrinks in width and never scrolls horizontally. This works for me......

Comment: Moreover, I again checked with putting Group in place of HBox and the issue came again... So the perfect solution would be as ItachiUchiha suggested to use re-sizable HBox instead of Group and setFitToWidth must be true to make the contents in the ScrollPane to avoid the empty space created while re-sizing or maximized..

Answer (score 0):

You may use **setFitToWidth** of the ScrollPane Object to match a particular dimension. For more details you may refer to the link http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/scrollpane.htm at down the page, Resizing Components in the Scroll Pane, you may find more on the solution